# Using specific consumer group in event hub in Azure to input the event

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-synapse, azure-eventhub

I have 2 consumer groups in event hub. It is being used by Synapse to push event and then consumed by Azure function and then AZ function pushes to event hub and gets consumed by Logic App.
Name of Eventhub: school - Consumer group: Student, Teacher. Earlier I had two different event hubs for both work now I am using consumer group for that.

I was earlier using Synapse to push my event only in event hub and that was simple :
`https://myschool-integration.servicebus.windows.net/school/messages`

Need help to push data in specific Consumer group in this case Teacher.

In Azure function I use this code to push data to event hub, but not sure how to push it to specific consumer group.

```
def send_event_data_batch(json_string):
    try:
        producer = EventHubProducerClient.from_connection_string(
        conn_str=EVENT_HUB_CONNECTION_STR,
        eventhub_name=school,
        )
        with producer:
            event_data_batch = producer.create_batch()
            event_data_batch.add(EventData(json_string))
            producer.send_batch(event_data_batch)
    except:
        logging.error(f"Failed to send data to Event Hub")
        raise
```

I need to use consumer group because now every time an event reaches eventhub, it triggers both the function and logic app. So there are 2 attempts.

Comment: Regarding using specific consumer group, Refer this SO thread answer 1- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60313736/send-messages-to-and-receive-from-a-particular-consumer-group-in-azure-event-hub and So thread answer 2 - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61401331/how-to-map-incoming-messages-to-a-consumer-group-in-azure-eventhub and check if it helps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot publish events to a specific consumer group.  A consumer group is not a physical boundary for data, it is just a label to apply for a logical grouping of readers.

There is only one event stream for an Event Hub; all consumers read from it regardless of what consumer group they identify as.

Comment: Is there a way I can do it by any other means ? or Should I just create 2 different event hubs for this purpose ?

Comment: I'd start by questioning if Event Hubs is the correct service for your scenario.  Unless you've got very high scale, this seems more suited to Service Bus with subscriptions that can be filtered.   But, if you're set on Event Hubs, then yes - each Event Hub instance is a new and distinct event stream.   That would be the best approach to splitting them out.